# Can't log into MySQL as root, even after restarting with --skip-grant-tables

Tags: mysql, root

I'm running MySQL 5.0.77 on FreeBSD 7.3.  The MySQL root password was lost, and I want to reset it.  But I have the following problem.

I stopped MySQL and re-started with the `--skip-grant-tables` option:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysqld start --skip-grant-tables
```

The service starts, but then when I try to log in without a password:

```
 mysql -u root
```

I get this response:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I can log in as other users (that lack the SUPERUSER privilege), but not root. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking"` restarted the mariadb server and still got the access denied error with `sudo mysql -u root`.

What worked for me was this:

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
sudo mysql -u root
```

Now in the mysql console:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Got an error when I did:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

But this worked:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

Finished up with:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

Back on shell:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

For me, I could still connect using `mysql -u root` so I stopped the server in a bad way: get PID(s) with `ps -aux | grep mysql` and terminate them with `sudo kill -9 <pid>`

Once we are sure mysql server is not running, restart normal way:

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

Now password will be required again, but we know what root password is.

Before final `systemctl start mariadb`, might want to run `sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS=""` to be safe in case you had attempted with that method.

Answer (score 0):

I've just passed by some similiar situation, after some frustration I've realized that I have 2 MySQL installations running in my computer, one in my OS and one in a local server package. In my case this annoying situation just got resolved shutting down the SQL service of my OS